# Difference between these three URL's?

Tags: url, query-string, url-routing, anchor

Can somebody explain how does it matter to pass different parameters in a url,

e-g

```
1: www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/file.html?param=9?val=ty5?test
2: www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/file.html#param=93#val=t5y5?test=9
3: www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/file.html&param=9?val=ty5&test=90#poiu
```

Basically I want to know what do these three characters `(#, &, ?)` do in the url. I have seen them most of the times? can I use some thing other than that 
e-g: `www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/file.html*param=9_val+ty5@test`

Comment: The way you use them above, they are invalid. You need to URL encode them. Which language are you asking about? You are mentioning three and one framework....

Comment: @Pekka I just gave examples, and I actually wanted to know does it matter that ? should come first then & and then # or is there some other constraint in there appearance in the url

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`?` indicates the start of the [query string](http://www.w3schools.com/asp/coll_querystring.asp)
`&` separates key value pairs of the querystring
`#` indicates an [anchor](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_a.asp). [Here](http://freepages.computers.rootsweb.ancestry.com/~pasher/anchors.htm)'s more on anchor links.

Note that all three of your urls are incorrect.

Valid url:

```
http://domain/path/file?name=value&name=value#anc
```

I notice you've edited your question with an additional question

> can I use some thing other than that e-g:
>   www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/file.html*param=9_val+ty5@test

You can use whatever you like in the part of the querystring or anchor as long as it is [url encoded](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: @Mike. That's not a valid url. Put the anchor after the querystring. Also, the url should only contain a single anchor.

Comment: @flem If my url is something like www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/file.html?param=9&param2=34......#val1=90&val2=op can i get it to execute without a backend script.

Comment: @Mike The browser WILL handle the url but it may not be the way you expect. It will read "val1=90&val2=op" as the anchor. I strongly recommend that you use urls in the [proper format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator#Syntax).

Comment: @flem let me explain in detail a bit as to what I am trying to acheive, please dont mind. I have a url and on click of an item something gets hidden, I want to pass this as a variable to the url meaning that if someone copies that url and puts in a new browser window, it should be able to show the updated result e-g
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/legend/itemhoverstyle/
here I want when series is hidden the url is changed and if someone takes the new url, he should get page with hidden graph.  Thanks a Million

Comment: @Mike. That's fine. What I'd recommend is: Firstly, use the correct url format. You don't want to have to come back in the future if new browsers start to complain. Use a comma separated list of values in the anchor like so: www.domain.com/folder1/folder2/file.html?param=9&param2=34......#val1=90,val2=op,val3=res. Use JS to pull the anchor from the url (as "val1=90,val2=op,val3=res") then split it on comma (`.split(',')`) to get each name-value pair. Process them at your will.

Comment: @flem Thanks dude, Assume I have the correct url format. can you tell me how do I save the url when the parameter us passed if graph is hidden. is there backend script involved here. actually I get the url correct but when I take the new url with appended parameters(in correct format) I dont see the new wndow showing graph as hidden. Is backend involved here

Comment: @Mike. Yes, you would need to use JS at this point to process the arguments on the url and display your graph appropriately. If you are struggling with this, I would recommend raising a new question specific to your JS requirements.

Comment: @flem but my question is, it backend involved here to save the url instance

Comment: @Mike. Your question is asking the difference between the characters ? & # in a url. I would suggest raising a new question for how to use JS to process arguments in the anchor of a url. You won't get anymore answers here based on these comments. The new question will be visible to all.

Answer (score 3):

This [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme) goes in to the detail and gives some good examples.

- A `?` indicates the start of the query
- A `&` separates the parameters in the query
- A `#` identifies a fragment in the `HTML` resource to be rendered. It's often used to identify which but if the page the browser should ensure is in view eg a heading etc

Answer (score 0):

? represents that the URL contains QueryString values.
& is used to for multiple querystring values. Example

```
www.abc.com/page?id=abc&pwd=def
```

and # is new for me I first time saw it.

Comment: # is an anchor. It makes the browser scroll to a location in the document.

Comment: Whilst all of this is true, the querystring and hash can also be used by, for example, jQuery or jQuery plugins. For example the jQuery tabs plugin uses the hash to decide which tab to show initially.

Answer (score -1):

- 1: ? is used for separating back end code to its arguments. Notice the file extension is html doesn't necessarily says that the back end code is in HTML
- 2: # is used to link to anchors within the html page
- 3: & is used for separating arguments with other arguments. in this case, the file.html is also an argument itself, while the backend code is the "/", which can be anything. e.g. index.php, default.asp, index.do. it all depends on your URL rewrite.

Comment: The client can also use/read the query string. It is not specific to code behind. If it IS html, it most likely will not have code behind.